# InverseMellinTransform producing two different results for the same input?

Tags: integral-transforms

Consider the expression

```
expr = Gamma[1 + s]/Gamma[1 - s] Gamma[-s]^2;
```

and a slightly simplified version of the same

```
expr2 = expr//FullSimplify
```

> [image]

If we take the `InverseMellinTransform` of the first shape of the expression `expr`, we get

```
InverseMellinTransform[expr, s, x]
```

> Log[1 + x]

On the other hand, if we take the `InverseMellinTransform` of the simplified form `expr2`, we get

```
InverseMellinTransform[expr2, s, x]
```

> Log[1 + 1/x]

Evidently, the two results do not agree. How to make sense of this? I assume, this is not correct behavior? Is there some way to do the transform more carefully in Mathematica, such that both calculations produce the same result consistently?

Comment: at least Mathematica is consistent. It gives back the same result  when transforming back :) screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9AdrF.png) may be there is some deep mathematical reason for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
expr = Gamma[1 + s]/Gamma[1 - s] Gamma[-s]^2;

imt1 = InverseMellinTransform[expr, s, x, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image]

```
MellinTransform[imt1 // Normal, x, s, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image]

Simplifying `expr`

```
expr2 = expr // FullSimplify

(* (π Csc[π s])/s *)

imt2 = InverseMellinTransform[expr2, s, x, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image]

```
MellinTransform[imt2 // Normal, x, s, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image]

The inverse transforms are for different regions.

```
InverseMellinTransform[expr, s, x,
  Assumptions -> 0 < Re[s] < 1] // 
   FullSimplify[#, 0 < x < 1] &

(* Log[1 + 1/x] *)
```